# Are classic Call-To-Actions appropriate in corporate website?

Tags: call-to-action, b2b

A company, which exports timber wants a corporate website. Is there any sense in classic call-to-action buttons in B2B sites, or are there any other practices?

Comment: As written, this question is way to vague. What 'calls to action' are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Just ask yourself what the goal of the site is.

Who's going to see it, what can the company do for them, and thus; what will the call to action be.

And if you don't know; ask *them*.

Answer (score 0):

A call to action implies by its existence that a user can **do something** on the corporate website, as opposed to simply **viewing something**.

If the corporate website presents more options than passive reading and viewing, and the tone of the writing is not "we-we-we" but more "you-you-you", then I think calls to action are a good fit.

They are part of a content strategy that includes action.

They should probably not invite a user to "Check out our **__**", but offer something tangible, like "View your order history" or "Download declaration form", or whatever is an appropriate action to take.

Answer (score 0):

Corporate site often reflects the corporation's structure with its departments etc. Typically different users have different goals and site's navigation should supports easy access to user's tasks.

While the Call-to-action is a highly visually distinct, one-click control for accessing to some important task. Are this task equally important for all users? I think, not always.

So the answer, use CTA for the task, that is equally important to perform by majority of users. An example of such task could be: a) some event registration; b) registration for some competition etc.

Answer (score 0):

Corperations are people too ([Corporate personhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood)), so treat it as you would any other website.

If you are talking about an internal tool which is only seen my employees managing the shipping or whatnot, tailor the UI to returning users. If you are talking about a company webpage, put the information visitors will need up front. Instead of a signup form, highlight their hours or contact info.

Take away: The content may change, but there is always a purpose behind a website. Emphasize that purpose, no matter what it is or who it is for.